# Protractor Image didn't upload on dialog box?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine, testing-framework

I want to test the image upload functionality using Protractor but my written script didn't work.

[image: This is the image dialogue box.]

When we click on the dialogue box image it opens the window to select the desired image. After the selection of the image, the box acts like below:

[image: image.]

I want to write a script through which I can upload an image and then click on the "Save" button.

[image: This is the css of a dialogue box.]

This is the Error message that encountered[image]

Given below is the script that I tried but doesn't work:

```
 var path = require('path');
 var fileToUpload = '../new image.jpeg';
 var absolutePath = path.resolve('__dirname', fileToUpload);
 console.log(absolutePath);
 var fileElem=element(by.css('label[for="cropper-file-input"]'));
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(fileElem), 2000,);
 fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: What is the outcome of trying to run your code? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Which line of code fails?

Comment: i have attached the error message with my question....kindly check it

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error, because you are trying to use 'sendKeys' method on an element whose type is not 'input'.

Use :

```
var fileElem=element(by.css('input[id="cropper-file-input"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
it('should upload a file', function() {
  var fileToUpload = '../some/path/foo.txt',

  absolutePath =path.resolve(__dirname,fileToUpload);

  element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);    
  element(by.id('uploadButton')).click();
});
```